# XSLT test to check whether <tr> parent node (<table>) has particular ID

Tags: css, xml, xslt, xpath, xhtml

I've been wrestling with the correct syntax for this and it boils down to:

How do I test to see if the parent node's attribute has a certain value?

I'm transforming some XHTML. I template match a `<tr>` in order to reformat the `colspan` attributes of some of the cells in that row. To add further confidence that this will only occur in certain tables, I need to check that the `<table>` the `<tr>` belongs to has a particular id attribute value.

```
<xsl:template match="tr">
<tr>
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="(count(td[@colspan='2'])=2 and count(td)=3)">
        <td colspan="1">
          <xsl:copy-of select="td[1]/node()" />
        </td>
        <td colspan="4">
          <xsl:copy-of select="td[2]/node()" />
        </td>
    </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*|node()" />
      </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</tr>
</xsl:template>
```

Here is the code I have so far. I either need to add further "ands" to my when test or another `xsl:if` or `xsl:when` to check the table attribute. For this instance, lets have the table id="Transformable".

To clarify, i only wish to do the above transformation when the table that the `<tr>` belongs to has an id of "Transformable".

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is it possible to post some of your source XML please? A sample would be perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you can use `parent` axis in your template match definition.

```
<xsl:template match="tr[parent::table/@id = 'Transformable']">
  This template matches only 'tr' within a 'table' with 'id' attribute which equals 'Transformable'.
</xsl:template>
```

*Update:* For complex nesting (if `table` is not a direct parent of `tr`) - you can use `ancestor` axis.

```
<xsl:template match="tr[ancestor::table/@id = 'Transformable']">
  This template matches only 'tr' within a 'table' with 'id' attribute which equals 'Transformable'.
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: +1 but be careful - it also depends on whether the tr is nested within a thead/tbody etc.

Comment: You're right. In the case of a long nesting I'd use 'ancestor::' instead of 'parent::'.

Comment: Hopefully there's no nested tables with one nested in another with the id='Transformable' or you'll match that too. That's why it would be good to see the Xml structure ;-)

Comment: Porbably safest is to test the innermost ancestor table: `ancestor::table[1]/@id = 'xyz'`

Comment: Fantastic. Thankyou all for your comments. I will use table[1] to be on the safe side.

Answer (score 0):

You should try something like (in you test clause):
    parent::table[@id = 'Transformable']

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the .. selector which stands for parent

```
<xsl:when test="..[@colspan='2']">
```